# Python User Input - Accepting Multiple Values Then Breaking

Tags: python, input, user-input, break

I would like for my input to keep asking for input and then breaking and running next code block when "no" is entered. The first question for input is "Who left at 2:30pm?", next it asks "Anybody else?". Names are entered and it will keep asking "anybody else?" until "no" is entered at which point the next code block should run. Please see my attached picture/snippet of my efforts and error I am obtaining here:

[image]

This is the code:

```
firstdrop = input("Who left at 2:30pm?")
df = df.drop(firstdrop)
second_drop = input("Anybody else?")
if second_drop == no:
  break
else:
    df = df.drop(second_drop)
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Put quotes around `"no"` , otherwise it treats `no` as a variable name.

Comment: You need to insert your code in a `while` or `for` loop.

Comment: As the error message says, you can't use `break` if you're not in a loop.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code has several syntax and semantic errors.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Prune Im not sure why this got a negative vote or what the issue is. Marino was able to provide the correct answer within 20 minutes so its obvious he understood what I was asking. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
firstdrop = input("Who left at 2:30pm?")
df = df.drop(firstdrop)
while True:
    second_drop = input("Anybody else?")
    if second_drop == "no":
        break
    else:
        df = df.drop(second_drop)
```

Comment: This did the trick! works beautifully, thanks so so much!!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept my answer if you think that it works good.